# CRM 2011 - Registering Multiple Plugins in One Assembly

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Just wondering what is the best practice to register multiple PLUGINS from one assembly. I have one project and multiple classes files (.cs files) where each of them represents a plugin. Currently when I registered the assembly I can see one plugin only in the registration tool.

Comment: Can you add the code for each plugin, or just verify that each one implements IPlugin

Comment: Each plugin class is implementing IPlugin. Do I have to use different namespace for each class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just figured it out. Only one class was set as public in my project. Changing all the classes to public resolved the issue and I can see all plugins in the registration tool.

Answer (score 0):

While using the plugin registration tool, you have to manually select the plugins that you'd like to register.  It doesn't automatically register the classes for you.

Comment: The registration tool is showing me one plugin only to select.

Comment: Any chance you have the plugin Gac'd on your machine that you're registering from?  Have you verified that all the other classes implement the plugin interface?

Comment: All classes are implementing IPlugin interface.I always use database to register plugins. I never used GAC.

Comment: @NawafKhalife - Good, the GAC is EVIL! (but necessary for plugins if you don't want to perform some sort of assembler hocus pocus)